# 'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, tensorflow, object-detection

code is

```
!mkdir {'Tensorflow\workspace\models\\'+CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME}
!cp {PRETRAINED_MODEL_PATH+'\ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_320x320_coco17_tpu-8\pipeline.config'} {MODEL_PATH+'\'+CUSTOM_MODEL_NAME'}
```

error is

```
'cp' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

please help me

Comment: Are you running this on Windows?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are running in windows.

try `!copy` instead of `!cp`

Comment: when i used the !copy i am getting the error as( The syntax of the command is incorrect.)

Comment: It is probably path issues. try to change / to \, enclose with " and so on.

Comment: Problem is solved. I launched the jupyter notebook with git bash